# Can I tell Google Cloud vision to isolate the largest (font size) text it reads in an image?

Tags: image-recognition, google-cloud-vision

I would like to use cloud vision to recognize and isolate the "main" text in a picture (say for instance the largest writing on packaging). I assume cloud vision would be able to do that on the backend by looking at the font size/how many pixels each letter takes up, but I am not sure whether there is an output for that in the API.

My best guess at where this info would be in the documentation is at the following link but I couldn't see anything related to this: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/reference/rest/v1beta1/documents/annotateText

Comment: Sounds like you have to do [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) first, then write some code to get the fragments with the largest font-size attribute... I'm not sure cloud vision helps you with that. OCR is not image recognition.

Answer (score 0):

`TEXT_DETECTION` Vision API 
(https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/samples#detecting_text_in_images)
can return arrays of (string + boundingPoly).

The json representation `AnnotateImageResponse` is below.

```
"textAnnotations": [
    {
      object(EntityAnnotation)
    }
  ]
```

`EntityAnnotation`
https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#EntityAnnotation

You can get the font size (in pixels) from `BoundingPoly`
https://cloud.google.com/vision/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#BoundingPoly

Comment: thats a wrong answer actually..basically there's no telling how big the poly is going to be around the text area ..at times visually smaller font can get encapsulated by a bigger box based on background noise etc ..there's got to be a more fool proof way to do this